# How to apply mutexes when passing by value?

Tags: c++, c++98

I was wondering how variable sharing works when I pass things by value. Would I lock a mutex before calling the function, and then unlock inside the function after entering? Is passing by value preferable when working with threads?

```
Mutex Que_mutex;
queue <char> Que;  //access to this must be done with Que_mutex locked
void queSizeCheck(queue<char> quet);

int main() {
//open new threads, which also manipulate Que
//some other code here, where Que.push, Que.pop and Que.front happens at some points
    Que_mutex.lock();
    queSizeCheck(Que);
}

void queSizeCheck(queue<char> quet) {
    Que_mutex.unlock();
    if (quet.size() < 3) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I am working on the mbed in C++98.

Comment: Some code example please, because I am not sure what might be the problem here. If you pass an object by value to a function, that object is copied, so even if you invoke that function in a thread, there is no need to lock anything (unless the copy of your object is not actual copy, and shares some resources).

Comment: @Ptaq666 you might need to lock a mutex to make a copy if another thread is modifying the original object at the same time which could lead to an inconsistent copy. As stated by others we need a [mcve] to answer your question.

Comment: @Ptaq666 I assumed copying involves reading, which can't happen if I am also writing to it in another thread. I will be using both write and read on this variable. I'll try to provide an example..

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer the question. Typically it's a bad idea to lock a mutex in one function and unlock it in another function, regardless of whether it's C or C++ (or any other language). 

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-guard-idiom-enhancing-the-scoped-loc/184401644

You can create ScopedLock in any version of C++ (it's part of the std now since c++11), that way you don't have to remember to unlock the mutex, it's done for you when the ScopedLock object lifetime ends e.g. end of a scope block or function return. NOTE: the lock is passed by reference.

Comment: Nothing is being passed by value in your code, so I don't understand what you're asking. And it doesn't make sense to conditionally unlock the mutex like you're doing.

Comment: @interjay I think it might be clearer now. I was prematurely posting it.

Comment: Global variables are a bad idea and will cause you problems eventually. Don't do that.

Comment: Did you really mean to pass `queSizeCheck` a copy of the queue? Why would `queSizeCheck`, a function that operates on its own copy of a queue, need to do anything with a global mutex? Since it's passed a queue by value, that queue can't possibly be shared with any other threads, can it? Why does `queSizeCheck` ignore the queue (`quet`) that was passed to it?

Comment: @interjay The queue is passed by value. But then, for some strange reason, the function ignores the queue that was passed to it by value.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz When I posted my comment it wasn't passed by value. In the current version, the function presumably accesses the queue in `//do something`.

Comment: @interjay It presumably access the queue after it unlocks the mutex that protects that queue?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My understanding is that the function only accesses a copy of the queue and therefore doesn't need the mutex locked there. OP wants to know how to lock the mutex only while reading the original queue (which is done when it is passed by value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why pass-by-value is kind of broken in C++98.

Since you want to hold the lock for the minimum time possible, in C++11 and C++14 I would copy the queue first, then unlock the mutex, then *move* the copy into the function (assuming `queue` is movable).

```
int main() {
    std::unique_lock<Mutex> lock(Que_mutex);
    auto copy = Que;
    lock.unlock();
    queSizeCheck(std::move(copy));
}
```

Since the question is tagged C++98, we can't use move semantics. In this case I would encapsulate the copying into a separate function and rely on the compiler being smart enough to apply copy elision:

```
queue<char> queCopy() {
    // lock_guard is C++11 but you can easily write your own C++98 implementation
    std::lock_guard<Mutex> lock(Que_mutex);

    // hope the compiler is smart enough to directly initialize the parameter
    // of queSizeCheck without incurring additional copies
    return Que;
}

int main() {
    queSizeCheck(queCopy());
}
```

This relies on the compiler eliding the copy of the return value of `queCopy` and of the argument of `queSizeCheck`. And ends up with the code actually being more well organised than the C++11 code. Starting in C++17, this once again becomes the better solution, due to mandatory copy elision.

All of this assumes a reasonable implementation of `queue`, which wasn't shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For sure. You are not even passing the `mutex` here. You are using the same `mutex`.
It will be unlocked.

Even if you pass the `mutex` in the function. It will still be unlocked.

However. It is not smart to lock the `mutex` in one function and unlock it in the other.
You should use approach like this.

```
mutex.lock()
//... some operations on the data structure
mutex.unlock()
```

You can look at RAII way of doing this with [lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard).

Comment: My mutex is global, why would I need to pass it?

Comment: @EskeyEski Your queue is global too, why would you need to pass that?

Comment: @EskeyEski no need to pass it. You can use it as global. You can use it as a private member in class if you use classes. Generally you don't want to pass the mutex unless you are injecting it as a dependency in a class.

Comment: @Oktalist so if my function is longer and uses queue many more times, then I don't need to lock all of that but only the moment its copied, which I thought might be better since other threads can still continue whenever they need to?

Comment: @EskeyEski Right. Your function uses a copy of the queue, not the original queue. Only the original needs to be protected by the lock. Other threads can't access the copy, unless the function explicitly shares it with them. This is assuming the implementation of the `queue` class doesn't do anything crazy like share data between copies.